# Assign variables for $_POST using a for loop

Tags: php, jquery, post

I'm sending data to php via jquery's `$.post()`.

```
$.post("data.php",
   {
    qty  : 2,
    len0 : "fruits",
    len1 : "furniture"
   }
```

How can I assign a variable to each $_POST? Below is what I tried but variables are not assigned.

```
$qty = $_POST['qty'];
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++){
   ${"len" . ($i)} = $_POST['len'].$i; //how do I assign variables to each POST?
};
```

Comment: Assignment -> *right* to *left*. `$_POST['len'][$i]`

Comment: @b0s3 thanks for your comment. :) Let me give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this, becuase you;re sending post variable `len0 : "fruits"`, so in php it would be `'len'.$i`

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++){
   ${"len" . ($i)} = $_POST['len'.$i];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the '[exract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)' function:

```
extract($_POST);
```

There will now be a variable (named after the array key) for each array item.

So you will now be able to do the following:

```
echo $qty; // 2
echo $len0; // "fruits"
echo $len1; // "furniture"
```

and so on.

I hope this helps.